# Evaluating $\displaystyle \int\;\frac {1}{2＋\sin(x)+\cos(x)}~~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

**Question:**
How to evaluate the integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{2+\sin x+\cos x}~~dx$$
Let:
$$
t＝\tan\left({\frac {x}{2}}\right)\implies\begin{alignedat}{3}\sin(x)＝\frac {2t}{1＋t^2} \\\cos(x)＝\frac {1-t^2}{1＋t^2}\\dx＝\frac {2}{1＋t^2}dt\end{alignedat}\\~\\\int\;\frac {1}{2＋\sin(x)＋\cos(x)}dx＝\int\frac {1}{2＋\frac {2t}{1＋t^2}＋\frac {1-t^2}{1＋t^2}}\frac {1}{1＋t^2}dt\\~\\＝\;\int\;\frac {1}{t^2＋2t＋3}dt$$

How to evaluate :
$$\int\;\frac {1}{t^2＋2t＋3}dt$$

Comment: $$\int\;\frac {dt}{t^2＋2t＋3}= \int\;\frac {dt}{(t+1)^2+2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\frac{t+1}{\sqrt2}
$$

Comment: @Mostafa You forgot to multiply the integral by $2$. Answer should be $\sqrt{2}\tan^{-1}\dfrac{t+1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\int\;\frac {1}{t^2＋2t＋3}dt$$

$$\frac {1}{t^2＋2t＋3}=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2+2}$$

Let $t+1=\sqrt2 u$

$$\frac {1}{t^2＋2t＋3}=\frac{1}{2(1+u^2)}$$

then

$$\int\;\frac {1}{t^2＋2t＋3}dt=\int\frac{1}{2(1+u^2)}\sqrt2 ~du=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan u+C=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan\frac{t+1}{\sqrt2}+C$$